# How to resolve ssl error jupyter notebook on Windows 10?

Tags: ssl, jupyter-notebook

I have already blown my mind over this. Whatever I do trying to run jupyter notebook on Win10, I get error:
PS D:\Users\Alex\miniconda3\condabin> jupyter notebook
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 198, in *run_module_as_main
File "", line 88, in *run_code
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE_*main**.py", line 4, in 
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\notebook\app.py", line 12, in 
from jupyter_server.base.handlers import JupyterHandler
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\jupyter_server\base\handlers.py", line 25, in 
from tornado import web
File "", line 1229, in *handle_fromlist
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado_*init**.py", line 66, in **getattr**
return importlib.import_module("." + name, **name**)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap.*gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\web.py", line 92, in 
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\httpserver.py", line 32, in 
from tornado.http1connection import HTTP1ServerConnection, HTTP1ConnectionParameters
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\http1connection.py", line 34, in 
from tornado import iostream
File "", line 1229, in *handle_fromlist
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado_*init**.py", line 66, in **getattr**
return importlib.import_module("." + name, **name**)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\importlib_*init**.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\iostream.py", line 40, in 
from tornado.netutil import ssl_wrap_socket, _client_ssl_defaults, _server_ssl_defaults
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 35, in 
_client_ssl_defaults = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 775, in create_default_context
context.load_default_certs(purpose)
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 596, in load_default_certs
self._load_windows_store_certs(storename, purpose)
File "D:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\ssl.py", line 588, in _load_windows_store_certs
self.load_verify_locations(cadata=certs)
ssl.SSLError: [X509] unknown error (_ssl.c:4035)

Please help, I was unable to find any solution to this. All installation manuals are like just take it easy: install and run, like a piece of cake. Like you run it and a browser just pops up. Doesn't happen for me.

Tried to reinstall openssl, self-signed and paid ssl certificates, resolve domain to local ip, install jupyter with or without miniconda and conda. Nothing helps.